# Camera2 OpenGL random glitches in video caused by Matrix.rotateM

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera2, grafika

I used the Grafika app and modified it to use the Camera2 API instead of the old API. I needed to use an OpenGL solution as I need to draw a watermark on top of the video, and Grafika was really useful. Unfortunately, my output videos are recording with random "flickers" of frames in the wrong orientation. I am looking to resolve the flickering issue, or at least understand why it is happening.

Originally, I managed to successfully record video, with sound, and drawing the watermark on top, but the video was in the wrong orientation as I required portrait videos. In order to achieve this, I used `MediaMuxer.serOrientationHint()` to configure the output file as portrait, and also applied a rotation to the transform matrix to ensure OpenGL frames were drawn in portrait, see below:

```
private void handleFrameAvailable(float[] transform, long timestampNanos) {

    mVideoEncoder.drainVideoEncoder(false);

    Matrix.rotateM(transform, 0, 270, 0, 0, 1); //Added these to rotate video frames
    Matrix.translateM(transform, 0, -1, 0, 0); //Added these to rotate video frames

    mFullScreen.drawFrame(mTextureId, transform);

    //...drawing of watermark happens here...//

    if (VERBOSE) { Log.e(TAG,"HandleVideo: "+timestampNanos); }
    mInputWindowSurface.setPresentationTime(timestampNanos);
    mInputWindowSurface.swapBuffers();
}
```

See below a regular frame and a glitched frame. In a 5 second video, around 20-30 non-consecutive frames may be like this.

[image: good frame]
[image: bad frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't resetting transform to identity matrix then you are accumulating transforms on each frame.
Try:

```
Matrix.setIndentityM(transform, m);
```

before apply translation and rotation.

Besides, could be orientation:

```
if (AppSetting.getValue(activity, Config.ORIENTATION, "").equalsIgnoreCase("Portrait")) {
    Matrix.rotateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, 270, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.translateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, -1, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give your first option a try as soon as I can. What is weird is that it is not every frame, just every now and then - seems random. The second solution may not be applicable as I force all activities in my app to be in portrait in the manifest. I will still take a look though, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Jose. Found the solution. A week or so ago I went through and tried to remove allocations to reduce garbage collections and memory allocations in loops. I moved the matrix array initialization outside of the loop thinking it would save memory. It probably did save memory, but it also meant the matrix wasn't being cleared each time and was impacting subsequent frames. So although your answer wasn't the exact issue, it did help me find the root cause. Thanks for your help.